# Django - for each record in database, multiply two values and find the sum

Tags: python, django

I'm learning Python and Django currently... I have a database with the following fields:

ID, amount, number

I want to multiply (amount * number) for each record in database, to assign result to variables, and after that to find a sum of all variables.

For example:

Database:

1. 100 14
2. 50  12
3. 80  10
4. 60  15
   .
   .
   . etc

I want to achieve this:

```
a = 100 * 14
b = 50 * 12
c = 80 * 10
d = 60 * 15
.
.
.etc
```

and after that, to find a SUM (a+b+c+d....etc), and to display that value in my template.

What I have done:

**VIEWS:**

```
def report(request):
    prof = Test.objects.all()
    response = TemplateResponse(request,'report.html', {'all': prof})
    return response
```

**MODELS:**

```
class Test(models.Model):
    number1= models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
    amount= models.IntegerField()
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    @property
    def profit(self):
        a = self.amount * self.number1
        return a
```

**TEMPLATE**

```
{% for games in all %}
    {{ games.profit }} <br>
{% endfor %}
```

The code above is displaying the multiplied results for each record in database, but I do not know how to find the SUM of all those new values?

Any help will be appriciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Calculate the sum in views and put it into a template variable.

**view**:

```
def report(request):
    all_objects = Test.objects.all()
    profits = [obj.profit for obj in all_objects]
    sum_profit = sum(profits)
    response = TemplateResponse(request,'report.html', {'profits': prof, 'sum': sum_profit})
    return response
```

**template**:

```
{% for each_profit in profits %}
    {{ each_profit }} <br>
{% endfor %}
<p>Sum: {{sum}}</p>
```